# How do I sanitize/clean up string values within Javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, object, data-cleaning, trim

I'm trying to find the best way to take data from a form input and remove extraneous white space from strings before they are submitted to our database via an API call. I'm working with React in next.js

The data takes this form:

```
const data = { 
  email: 'test@testemail.com',
  website: 'http://www.fake.com'
  name: 'Fake Name  '
}
```

And I want to avoid having users submit strings with empty spaces at the end to avoid database issues. Currently, I have a `.trim()` on event handlers called on the actual form inputs themselves but want an API call failsafe to dry up the code a little bit. Just can't figure out the best way to do this.

Comment: Maybe try `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "")`

Comment: Having `.trim()` calls on each value is the recommended best practice. There might be other values that you *don't* want to "clean up", so you really shouldn't do a catch-all script.

Comment: "*to avoid database issues*" - why would your database not be able to handle spaces at the end of strings? But if it really can't, then you definitely should do this sanitisation at the server side anyway, not in the react event handlers.